# How could I make labels appear as "large size" when inline form in Bootstrap?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

According to the Bootstrap [documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/css/#forms-control-sizes):

> Quickly size labels and form controls within .form-horizontal by
>   adding .form-group-lg or .form-group-sm.

I am trying to create an **inline** form and change the default size of all elements within my form to a "large" or "lg" size.

Whenever I try to combine these two examples (horizontal form and inline form) provided by the Bootstrap docs, I seem to be unable to apply these rules to solve the problem I am having (make sure to run it in full page):

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <!-- The example code provided on the Bootstrap documentation:-->
      <!--<form class="form-inline">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="exampleInputName2">Name</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputName2" placeholder="Jane Doe">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="exampleInputEmail2">Email</label>
          <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail2" placeholder="jane.doe@example.com">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Send invitation</button>
      </form>-->


      <!-- What I am actually trying, is to add form-horizontal here (so that I can profit from the form-group-lg's functionality): -->
      <form class="form-inline form-horizontal">
        <!-- And form-group-lg here: -->
        <div class="form-group form-group-lg">
          <!-- And control-label here: -->
          <label for="exampleInputName2" class="control-label">Name</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputName2" placeholder="Jane Doe">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <!-- And control-label here -->
          <label for="exampleInputEmail2" class="control-label">Email</label>
          <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail2" placeholder="jane.doe@example.com">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Send invitation</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/psxda5yv/)

The layout of the form elements will be broken (one of the labels will flow over the input and the first label will flow outside of the container element). How is this to be handled within Bootstrap? Should I just add a `input-lg` class to the input instead? Is it not possible to resize the label this way?

Answer (score 0):

Just add to the 2 wrappers of the input group a col-lg-12 (or other breakpoint according to your needs), in order to make them responsive.

```
<div class="form-group form-group-lg col-lg-12">
          <!-- And control-label here: -->
          <label for="exampleInputName2" class="control-label">Name</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputName2" placeholder="Jane Doe">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-lg-12">
          <!-- And control-label here -->
          <label for="exampleInputEmail2" class="control-label">Email</label>
          <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail2" placeholder="jane.doe@example.com">
        </div>
```

Comment: This is not solving my problem. The form-group elements will still flow over one another's padding. I do not think Bootstrap was designed this way to fix something so commonly used (inline-forms) to be so custom changed just to change label sizes?

Comment: i tested it, the padding is fixed, open your own fiddle and add col-lg-12 to both form-group divs

Answer (score 0):

The Problem is that the css of `form-inline` and `form-horizontal` are in **conflict** with each other.

> You **can't combine** them, because of there are many problems like the
>   **negative margin** from `form-horizontal` and **several paddings** etc. This rules are the reason why your layout breaks. Its simply not
>   implemented to be combined.

But you could get `form-group-lg` and `form-group-sm` working on `form-inline`. Sometimes it helps to take a look at bootstraps css, copy something and adapt it to your needs like i did below:

**Source:** ([bootstrap.css](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v3.4.1/dist/css/bootstrap.css))

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .form-horizontal .form-group-lg .control-label {
    padding-top: 11px;
    font-size: 18px;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .form-horizontal .form-group-sm .control-label {
    padding-top: 6px;
    font-size: 12px;
  }
}
```

**Result:** (changed from `.form-horizontal` to `.form-inline` and removed padding)

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .form-inline .form-group-lg .control-label {
    font-size: 18px;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .form-inline .form-group-sm .control-label {
    font-size: 12px;
  }
}
```

Done. :) Take a look at the example below:

```css
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .form-inline .form-group-lg .control-label {
    font-size: 18px;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .form-inline .form-group-sm .control-label {
    font-size: 12px;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <form class="form-inline">
        <div class="form-group form-group-lg">
          <label for="exampleInputName2" class="control-label">Name</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputName2" placeholder="Jane Doe">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="exampleInputEmail2" class="control-label">Email</label>
          <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail2" placeholder="jane.doe@example.com">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group form-group-sm">
          <label for="exampleInputEmail2" class="control-label">Email</label>
          <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail2" placeholder="jane.doe@example.com">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Send invitation</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```